# $(...).mCustomScollbar is not a function (JavaScript Modules and Dependencies)

Tags: scroll, aurelia

Having trouble setting up malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin.

I installed it as follows:

```
jspm install mCustomScrollbar=npm:malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin
```

I import it to the relevant viewmodel as follows:

```
import mCustomScrollbar from 'mCustomScrollbar';
...
$('.article').mCustomScrollbar();
```

I get the following error:

> $(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function

looking at the dev-tools:network, the library has loaded ??

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1) you've spelled mCustomScrollbar wrong (missing the r in Scroll)
2) you need to required the css in the template otherwise the plugin fails to load

(your css location may differ)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jspm_packages/npm/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin@3.0.9/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
<template>
...
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Fixed spelling, but this did not solve it for me. I get the error before my view (template is loaded), so the css does not get a chance to load.

Answer (score 0):

check the script file loaded or not...
      `$.getScript( "/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js" )
     .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
       console.log( textStatus );
       DataBind();
     })
      .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
       $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
    });`